# Send unlimited args on command line with value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to build a generic file for create a table on database I want from command line send something like this `python create_table.py table_name=test name=TEXT city=TEXT`

So every time I run the file I can create a new table with new fields every field with his type

I figure out to use `sys.argv` and send it like this

```
python create_table.py test name TEXT city TEXT ...etc
```

and take sys.arg[1] as table name and sys.argv[2] as first column and sys.argv[3] as the type of it and the other column like this with unlimited of column number every time I run the code send different number of columns.

My question is there is any better way than using `sys.argv` ?

my code now look like this

```
import sqlite3
import sys
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/'+sys.argv[1]+'.db')
print ("Opened database successfully");
query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + sys.argv[2] +' ('
for i in range(3,len(sys.argv[3:]),2):
        if i != 3:
                query +=', '
        query+= sys.argv[i] +' ' +sys.argv[i+1]
query += ')'
print(query)
conn.execute(query)
print ("Table created successfully");
conn.close()
```

Comment: take a look at argparse in python :)

Comment: Don't bother splitting the columns, since it hardly saves any typing - just put them all together in quotes and include commas: `python create_table.py test "name TEXT,age INT,city TEXT"`. Then you can do: `f'CREATE TABLE {sys.argv[1]} ({sys.argv[2]})'`. In the long run, this will be much more flexible than trying to extract all the individual elements using a command-line parser.

Comment: All commandline parsers use `sys.argv`.  Use it directly if you don''t want to limit names etc.  Use something like `argparse` for user help and error checking.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: suppose you want to add some extra params to the columns. You could easily end up with something like this: `python create_table.py test name TEXT UNIQUE age INT city TEXT NOT NULL`. It can quickly get quite tricky to parse when the params aren't all the same length, so it's better to keep them all together as a single argument using quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for such use cases.

```py
import argparse

def main():
    # Create ArgumentParser object
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create a database table')

    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument('table_name', type=str, help='Name of the table')
    parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help='Name entry')
    parser.add_argument('city', type=str, help='City entry')

    # Parse the command-line arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Print the arguments
    print(f"Table Name: {args.table_name}")
    print(f"Column Name: {args.name}")
    print(f"Column Type: {args.city}")

main()
```

Comment: this will just let me add two column I add name and city as example I will change them every time I run the code

Comment: You can use argparse for same like so: `parser.add_argument('array_args', nargs='*', help='Array arguments')` (array of arguments)

Comment: Taking all strings in with `nargs='*'` is no improvement over looking at `sys.argv` directly - unless you want other `argparse` features, like the help, and handling of `optionals`.  `arpgarse` provides some structure for your end user (or you six months from now).  If you don't need that structure, don't use it.